# Recreate content entity table in Drupal 8

Tags: mysql, drupal, drupal-modules

I have a custom module and just created a content entity using `drupal generate:entity:content`.

Played a bit with it, and deleted table from PHPMyAdmin.

Now, I am unable to recover it back, I tried to create table again, but `drush updatedb --entity-updates` does not help to get table back in shape. Looks like table metadata lives somewhere else.

How can I rebuild the table?

**UPDATE:**

Achieved by reinstalling the module. Please share if there is a better way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I can't uninstall the module because base table not found error.

```
drupal update:entities
```

This command creates the missing entity table for me.